# How implements a 'fake' directory using Java, C# or C++

Tags: java, c#, c++, filesystems

I want to intercept third-party software read commands, made in a given directory of the local windows filesystem, to return to it files from a managed Oracle database. 
Let's suppose the following example:

1. The third-party software makes a `dir` command in the directory `C:\processingfiles`
2. The `C:\processingfiles` is a "fake" directory that redirects the command for a custom application (Java, C#, C++).
3. The custom application, receive the command `dir` and returns the result from a database query;
4. Then, the third-party software requires a given file, for example `load file.txt`, from the `C:\processingfiles`;
5. The custom application, receive the command `load file.txt` and queries the database to return the binary file.
6. The third-party software gives sequence in the `load` command.

Therefore, It's possible to use a programming language like Java, C# or C++, to mount a filesystem directory in a Windows environment, and manage the operations made in this directory?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`libfuse`](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse#libfuse) and its [Windows compatibility layer](https://superuser.com/questions/179436/is-it-possible-to-use-fuse-with-windows/1428914#1428914).

Comment: Sounds like you want to write a kernel module.

Comment: @G.M. that's sounds quite informative. Can you point out a more focused example for my described scenario?

Comment: I'm not aware of any code that exactly mirrors your needs but you should probably have a look at the [examples in the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace#Application).

Comment: I've found another possibility. This link [winfsp](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp)